# Compare API response against itself

Tags: node.js, api, axios, response

I am trying to:

- Poll a public API every 5 seconds
- Store the resulting JSON in a variable
- Store the next query to this same API in a second variable
- Compare the first variable to the second
- Print the second variable if it is different from the first
- Else: Print the phrase: 'The objects are the same' if they haven't changed

Unfortunately, the comparison part appears to fail. I am realizing that this implementation is probably lacking the appropriate variable scoping but I can't put my finger on it. Any advice would be highly appreciated.

````
  data: {
    chatters: {
        viewers: {
        },
    },
  },
};

//prints out pretty JSON
function prettyJSON(obj) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
}

// Gets Users from Twitch API endpoint via axios request
const getUsers = async () => {
  try {
    return await axios.get("http://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/sixteenbitninja/chatters");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

//Intended to display 
const displayViewers = async (previousResponse) => {
  const usersInChannel = await getUsers();
  if (usersInChannel.data.chatters.viewers === previousResponse){
      console.log("The objects are the same");
  } else {      
      if (usersInChannel.data.chatters) {
            prettyJSON(usersInChannel.data.chatters.viewers);
            const previousResponse = usersInChannel.data.chatters.viewers;
            console.log(previousResponse);
            intervalFunction(previousResponse);
        }
   } 

};

// polls display function every 5 seconds
const interval = setInterval(function () {
    // Calls Display Function
    displayViewers()
}, 5000);```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using equality operator `===` on objects. two objects are equal if they have the same reference. While you want to know if they are identical. Check this:

```js
console.log({} === {})
```

For your usecase you might want to store stringified version of the `previousResponse` and compare it with stringified version of the new object (`usersInChannel.data.chatters.viewers`) like:

```js
    console.log(JSON.stringify({}) === JSON.stringify({}))
```

**Note:** There can be issues with this approach too, if the order of property changes in the response. In which case, you'd have to check individual properties within the response objects.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use npm packages like following

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@radarlabs/api-diff